# Find a basis, and determine the dimension, for the space of all 2 × 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

[image]

So I understand how to find the basis and dimensions for linearly independent matrices, however this matrix is linearly dependent, I tried to look if any of the matrices can be created using the other two and scalars, however I could not find anything. I'm pretty lost, so any help would be very appreciated.

M = a[3 0, -7 -3] + b[0 -1, 6 0] + c[-1 -3, 5 1].  However these matrices are dependent and idk how to make progress

Comment: Could you do this if these were vectors in $\Bbb R^4$ instead of matrices?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why do you say these matrices are dependent?

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023) regarding how to display matrices

Comment: So I found out you can't find a basis if they are dependent, so I'm assuming that I made a mistake in assuming that these are linearly dependent. Let me try using a different method to see if they are independent. Because if they are, then the basis is simply that set of matrices and the dimension is 4.